# Angular project shows blank page on some computers at the same network

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I run an angular 2 project with ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000 and try to access it from computers on the same network. On some computers it loads perfectly and on some it shows an empty page with no error in the console. I checked the index page html and i see there the title and the icon but no directives on the app-root or the styles in the header.
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: With command are you using to run your app?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: what browser and version are you using ? please provide more info, we don't have crystal balls !

Comment: Which ip are you using to load the page? it should be something like  192.168.X.X:4000

Comment: Try also using ng serve --host 192.168.X.X using the ip of your computer

Comment: The angular version is 8.0.3 and the chrome is 55

Comment: can you update  you chrome to last version

Comment: I will try i think that is the problem.

Comment: Do you know what is the minimum chrome version angular supports?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: thank you for the reaponse but The article shows the latest version of chrome support but doesn't show the minimum

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000 --disable-host-check
```

and be sure that in that computer firewall allow it

[image]

Comment: The problem is i dont have admin permission